# Town Car over heating problem

Tags: overheating, lincoln

I have a 1996 Lincoln Town Car 4.6 liter v8 engine. I have replaced the water pump due to it leaking and car running hot. It still ran hot, so i replaced the radiator, thermostat, and the cap that goes to the coolant. My car is still running hot and I am not getting any pressure in the area that I put the coolant in. Usually I can't take the cap off due to it being so hot and it might go into my face but instead its not. Please help if ya can thanks.

Temp reads hot on the digital screen and the coolant tank is full.

Comment: How do you know it is running hot? More details please. Is there coolant in the coolant tank?

Comment: my car says its running hot , i have a digital screen , yes there is coolant in the tank

Comment: Does it run hot all time? Idle, Heavy traffic and cruise at 60mph?

Comment: I'm wondering if the thermostat got put in upside down and now is keeping coolant from flowing correctly. Not sure if this is possible on the 4.6l engine, but it sure seems like a possibility.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Most tstat covers do not allow for this, they are aggie proof

Comment: @charlie what does the digital readout say the temp is?

Comment: @Moab - I've seen stupider things happen. It's amazing what people can accomplish. Could also be a bad thermostat from the store, though highly unlikely.

Comment: I have had new water pumps with blocked ports.

Comment: Bleeding is an art, and if not bled properly can cause the same symptoms.  Did the new thermostat have that tiny loose rivit in the flange?  I would try filling the cooling system and running at idle, topping up as necessary, squeezing the upper hose at intervals, until there are absolutely no more bubbles.

Comment: I meant to mention this is with the cap off, heater on high, and sometimes it helps to have the vehicle on a slight incline -- in this case front wheels slightly higher than rears (helps to "burp" the heater core).  I can't say that this will solve your problem, but I can say that if it's not properly bled, that's a *problem in itself*...

Comment: You need to put a thermometer in the radiator and see what the actual temp is when the car gauge says it is overheating. It may be lieing to you. It may just be a bad sender/sensor.

Answer (score 1):

Did you test the new thermostat in a clear glass with hot water from a kettle? did you actually see it open when you poured hot water into the glass?
you could have tested the old one first, how do you know you have the right thermostat for the engine? Are the cooling fans/fan working when the engine gets to hot?